# React Native class variable shows two different values...what is the explanation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Heres's my sample code...with most things stripped out...

```
class MyView extends Component {

aFlag = true //initialize class variable here

componentDidMount() {
 // for some reason even after this component unmounts and mounts again this class variable stays at false (a value that we set in this compoment at some point)...
 this.aFlag = true // (1) ***** IF I TAKE THIS OUT...the console log for this.aFlag below is FALSE
 console.log('this', this) // (2) shows a MyView Object, aFlag key has value FALSE!!!
 console.log('this.aFlag:', this.aFlag)// (3) this console log show TRUE

//other code here that uses this.aFlag removed...

}
...

renderItem = () => {
//other code removed...
if (some condition) this.aFlag = false
}

render(){
<Flatlist
renderItem={this.renderItem}
...other code removed
/>
}
```

I have a simple class with a class variable initialized to true in the class definition.

Here's what happens.
Instantiate the component...componentDidMount logs what I show above in comments.  Why is that?

Why does the console log of `this` show `aFlag` as `false`

What is the console.log of `this.aFlag` referencing?

Am I having a scope issue?

Comment: Why is that? Doesn’t the class variable get initialized?

Answer (score 0):

look at lifecycle diagram [here](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).
it seems `renderItem` executes before `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `componentDidMount` is called after `render`. If you set it to false in `render` then it’ll be false in `componentDidMount`.

You can use the `constructor` instead if that’s an issue, as it is called before `render`.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Even if I move that to the constructor, I still see it as false.

Comment: Then there’s something in the code you removed that is affecting it.

Comment: Can you look at (1), (2), and (3)?  I set aFlag in (1), but the console log in (2) shows and object with that key as false...BUT (3) console logs this.aFlag...and that is true for some reason.  (Those lines of code do not have any async stuff)